# GC overhead limit exceeded when compiling with Google Cloud Dataflow dependency

Tags: sbt, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

When I add the library dependency

`"com.google.cloud.dataflow" % "google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all" % "2.4.0"`

to my project and then run it using SBT, an error saying

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

occurs during the compilation.

Any ideas on why this happens?

Comment: where are you running it from? can you increase the heap size?

Comment: Do you have a job_id?

Comment: Are you actually running a dataflow pipeline? Or linking the dep into some other program? This is just failing in a build step with sbt scala build tool?